# javascript + send multiple strings with URL

Tags: php, javascript, xml, get

I have a script that calls another php page and passes values using PHP get.

The one variable, q is sent with the URL where str is a variable.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str,true);
```

I have a few multiple variables that I want to send in the URL string.

How can I send multiple variables.

Along the lines of:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str+"y="+str2+"z="+str3,true);
```

where the URL will then be somthing like

```
page.php?q=Peter&y=John&z=Smith
```

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str+"&y="+str2+"&z="+str3,true);`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to separate them with an ampersand, and probably URL-encode them too:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?"
    + "q=" + encodeURIComponent(str)
   + "&y=" + encodeURIComponent(str2)
   + "&z=" + encodeURIComponent(str3), true);
```

Also, no problem ;)

Comment: +1 I just feel like downvoting all the other answers that don't mention encoding...

Answer (score 3):

Seems you just forgot the ampersands:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str+"&y="+str2+"&z="+str3,true);
                                         ^          ^
```

But, more important, you need to [escape the strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent):

```
str = encodeURIComponent(str);
```

before using them as url parameters. See also [this article](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75980/1048572) on encode-functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an ampersand between strings:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str+"&y="+str2+"&z="+str3,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're practically there, the only thing missing from your request/uri is the ampersand between the request parameters:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str+"&y="+str2+"&z="+str3,true);
```